# How to access a child element that is located inside ng-template by its id in a parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

this is pretty straightforward and I could not find any solution that works for me, including reading the Angular documentation.
So, I want to access a child component from its parent by the child's id because I want to use it in Jasmine unit test for the parent component.
The problem is that the child component is inside ng-template.

And I don't have a reference to it. I tried different solutions, none of them work.

This is an example code:
This ng-template is located in the parent component:

```
<ng-template #templateName>
   <child-component id="child-component"></child-component>
</ng-template>
```

And in the **parent component**:

```
@ViewChild('templateName') template;
```

How to access the `<child-component> </child-component>` by its id by the parent?

Any help would bre greatly appreciated!
 Thank you!

Comment: could you try to describe, why you need to access this component. maybe there is a better solution, that accessing the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#yourId').nativeElement;
```

Or you have as well:

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(YourComponent)).nativeElement;
```

Comment: I don't think authour is asking about tests

Comment: He said “ So, I want to access a child component from its parent by the child's id because I want to use it in Jasmine unit test for the parent component.”. He already have access to the Child component in his parent if it wasn’t about tests